# making an arraylist of extended classes in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Is it OK if I make an arrayList of objects of extended class.

EX:

```
Class A {
  private aa;
}
Class B extends A {
  private ArryList <A>;
}
```

I want that my class B should have all the values of A and an array list of A.

is there any other way of doing this except making two different classes with same parameters ?

Or this method will work for me?

Comment: Make ArrayList in Class A as protected

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply,I want to use both A and B as individual objects . so I cant make an arraylist in A.

Comment: Also your question is not quite clear

Comment: sorry for that.....   actually i am making an android aplication which has comments and replies.  Both comments and replies have same parameters in API but comments can have an array of replies. I want to display comments and replies both. SO i was thinking if I could do like that.........

Comment: then my above solution should work

Comment: Sorry once again but..I am not getting your point...Actually I am fairly new to JAVA so can you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I suggest you to read basics of access modifiers in Java, it's very difficult to explain that big thing in this comment box :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use getter and setters like this:

```
Class A {
  private int aa;
  public int getAA(){
    return aa;
  }
  public void setAA(int aa){
    this.aa = aa;
  }
}
Class B extends A {
  private ArryList <A> aaa;
}
```

also you may do as say @Pradeep Simha and make `protected int aa` and now you can get access to aa field from B class

Comment: ..thanks for your reply.. I was thinking for the same thing... so that I can use all the elements of A  in B + and arraylist of A ....

Answer (score 0):

Your design should work.

```
class Reply
{

}

class Comment extends Reply 
{
    private List<Reply> repliesToComment;
}
```